# How to convert a condition check from C# to Java?

Tags: java, c#, code-conversion

I am attempting to convert this line of code from C# TO Java and I am having quite a hard time wrapping my head around it.

```
isEqual = !dbCertDict.Keys.Any(x => !String.Equals(dbCertDict[x], requestCertDict.ContainsKey(x) ? requestCertDict[x] : "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Originally, the dbCertDict was of type `Dictionary<string, string>`, it is now of type `HashMap<String, String>`. Essentially I want to write in Java a function that will set `isEqual` to true if there is a match for all of the items in both dbCertDict and requestCertDict. And I want it to return false if there are any mismatches.

At least, that's what I think this line of C# code is doing...Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to search for an equivalent function to `Any()` but the closest that I could find was to replace `dbCertDict.Keys.Any` with `dbCertDict.keySet().contains()` but they are not the same unfortunately...

Comment: @MaythamFahmi I suppose nothing. Just thought I would use something available in an existing library if I could. If I need to, I could definitely write my own, but I am asking this in case I do not need to

Comment: I got you, that is fair enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
isEqual = !dbCertDict.Keys.Any(x => 
!String.Equals(dbCertDict[x], requestCertDict.ContainsKey(x) ?
requestCertDict[x] : "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

boolean isEqual = !dbCertDict.keySet().stream().anyMatch(x ->
dbCertDict.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(requestCertDict.containsKey(x) ?
requestCertDict.get(x) : ""));
```

or something along those lines.

The latter can be tightened to

```
boolean isEqual = dbCertDict.entrySet().stream().noneMatch(x -> 
x.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(requestCertDict.getOrDefault(x.getKey(), "");
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize that Stream had a function like anyMatch(), this will probably work. I'll accept once I test it :)